# How to read pointer of class from file

Tags: c++

I am trying to write pointers of a class into file and then reading it. Writing is just fine, but reading shows error of type conversion. Help please.
Take example of this(integer).. If we use int instead of int* then code executes but not fine.

```
#include<iostream>    
#include<windows.h>
#include<fstream>
using namespace std;   
void save(int *ptr)
{
    ofstream data;
    data.open("info.txt",ios::app);
    if (data.is_open())
    {
        data<<ptr;
        data.close();
    }
    else 
    {
        cout << "Unable to open file";
    }

}

int* loaddata()
{
    ifstream data;
    int ptr;


    data.open("info.txt");
    if (data.is_open())
    {
        while (!data.eof() )
        {
            data>>ptr;
        }

        data.close();
    }
    else 
    {
        cout << "Unable to open file";
    }

    return ptr;


}

void main()
{
    int a=0;

    save(&a);

    int *ptr=loaddata();
}
```

Comment: And were supposed to guess what's wrong? We can't help you if you don't post your code.

Comment: @Borgleader bet he's trying to convert string to a pointer

Comment: How do you know writing is just fine?

Comment: What case do you want to save a pointer?

Comment: I have rolled back your edits to the previous version, as it is a completely different question, and the proposed answer makes no sense in the context of the new question.  Ask a new question and you'll get better answers.

Answer (score 2):

A pointer is just a memory address.  You can write it just fine, as you said, but when you *read* it, it is still just a memory address.  Unless the object that it was pointing to is at the exact same memory location when you read it, you will be "reading" a pointer to random data, which you cannot convert to the class of the object it was pointing to before.

It's like storing the location (lat/long) of a butterfly, then trying to find that butterfly just from that position.  The butterfly is most likley in a completely different place now.

Comment: @user2282085, you need to save values of all the object's fields and then read it from a file and create a new object

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying is that was normally called serialization.

The idea is to write class instances ( all data contained ) and an ID which can be the address of the instance because this is a very well unique id. Your serialization library takes care that only one instance is written ( as only one data set is needed ) and all later writes of this instance are done only by writing the pointer.

Reading back is quite simple as well. You serialization library knows that it needs a instance of a class, generate a new one with the content as written before if not already done with the unique id ( maybe the pointer/address as mentioned before ). After that every try to get a "read pointer" results in setting the pointer the actual value of the new generated instance.

Have a look for serializer pattern or a concrete implementation like boost::serialize  http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/libs/serialization/doc/index.html